# Unequal partition of a set by the orbits of a group action

Tags: abstract-algebra

The set $A$ can be partitioned using the orbits of elements of $A$ generated by a group action $F: G\times A\rightarrow A$. Each pair of the Cartesian product $(g,a)$ is sent to a permutation of $A$, so that the orbit of an element $a \in A$ is defined as $O_a=\{g\cdot a\,\vert\, g\in G\}$. I think I get it, but I wonder if I can get an example where the size of the partitions is not equal.

Here is an example:

[image]

after the [Wolfram entry on group orbits](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupOrbit.html).

Comment: Well that's the typical case, so if you try some simple examples you should be able to find a suitable example.

Comment: OK. Just going through the definitions for now.

Comment: I found this good [example on youtube](https://youtu.be/-tXKyHGRza0).

Comment: @MorganRodgers Sorry, I'm looking at all this material on my own and for the first time. Would you mind spelling out what the subgroup of $G$ generated by $\tau_1$ would be?

Comment: @MorganRodgers The example makes sense, but I wonder if you did a transcription mistake. I tend to think you meant: $O_1=O_2=\{1,2\}; O_3=\{3\}; O_4=\{4\}$, correct?